# Azure AD - B2B Invite to email that is not an actual email

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

We have an AD directory where we invite our users B2B way. Normally, they have their own email like `somename@thecompany.com` but not every time, this is an actual email address i.e. they cannot receive mails here. Therefore, we use a private email where they receive the invitation but then when they click  the `Get started` button, they are requested to create a new password and subsequently there is verification code sent to them BUT to this `somename@thecompany.com`account and not the private one.

Is there a way to redirect the verification code to the private email or disable it etc.? Any ideas how to go around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To skip the redemption process to access any resources he has been invited to, you can invite a member of that tenant and use that account invite other members. And to grant the member who was invited to your tenant can invite other users, you can active **Guest can invite** feature or you can invite the guest user using the PowerShell command to invite the user as **a member of your tenant** instead of **guest user**.

More detail about this, you can refer the blog below:

[Azure AD B2B: How to bulk add guest users without invitation redemption.](https://justidm.wordpress.com/2017/05/07/azure-ad-b2b-how-to-bulk-add-guest-users-without-invitation-redemption/)